# conio.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, unix

Here is a simple c code that I want to compile under an Ubuntu 12.04

```
$ fgrep -n '' elso.c 
1:#include "stdio.h"
2:#include "conio.h"
3: 
4:void main()
5:{
6:  int w,h;
7:  int area;
8:  printf("\nEnter the width of the rectangle ");
9:  scanf("%d",&w);
10:  printf("\nEnter the height of the rectangle ");
11:  scanf("%d",&h);
12:  area=w*h;
13:  printf("\nThe area of a rectangle is %d",area);
14:getch();
15:}
$ gcc elso.c -o elso
elso.c:2:19: fatal error: conio.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
$ head -1 /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS \n \l
```

**Q:** What is the "fatal error: conio.h: No such file or directory"?

Comment: [First google match for conio.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) -- `conio.h is a C header file used mostly by MS-DOS compilers to provide console input/output.[1] It is not described in The C Programming Language book, and it is not part of the C standard library, ISO C nor is it defined by POSIX.`

Comment: [conio.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) is not part of the standard c library, so don't expect to find it every where -> for example you linux says `no such file or directory`! You should avoid using it if you want to write portable C code.